# How does an SNMPv3 Agent know where to send a notification?

Tags: notifications, snmp

When an SNMPv3 agent generates a notification (e.g., per RFC 2981 Event MIB), how does the agent figure out what type of notification to send and where to send it? I assume the following RFC 3413 tables are used, but the linkages are not very well described (IMHO).
- snmpNotifyTable
- snmpNotifyFilterProfileTable
- snmpNotifyFilterTable

Step (1) of Section 3.3 of RFC 3413 indicates that the first step is to determine the management targets - but little guidance is provided to define how this works using the standardized objects. Logically, I would think that there would be a link between the notification name and the snmpNotifyName - that would then indicate whether a trap or inform is sent to which targets on a notification-by-notification basis, but the examples provided in RFC3413 seem counter to this logic and the definitions of the objects do not provide for such a linkage... Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB` objects configure *what* notifications the agent sends. `SNMP-TARGET-MIB` objects configure *where* the agent sends notifications. The linkage between the tables of the two MIBs (*what* notifications to send *where*) is configured through tag values/lists (e.g. `snmpNotifyTag` -> `snmpTargetAddrTagList`). In other words, a given target in `snmpTargetAddrTable` gets whatever notifications the agent is configured to send where such configuration's `snmpNotifyTag` appears in `snmpTargetAddrTagList`.

**Additional information per comments:**

In `DISMAN-EVENT-MIB`, a notification is configured to be sent based on configured triggering conditions. The notification to be sent is identified by the NOTIFICATION-TYPE OID assigned to `mteEventNotification`. Suppose whatever triggering condition occurs and the agent has decided to send that notification to all appropriate targets. Then, notifications will be sent as follows:

1. The agent will search through `snmpNotifyFilterTable` to find all rows where `mteEventNotification` matches the row's `snmpNotifyFilterSubtree` and `snmpNotifyFilterMask`, using `snmpNotifyFilterType` and precedence rules to determine whether that notification is included in or excluded from the profile.
2. For each `snmpNotifyFilterProfileName` determined above, where `mteEventNotification` is to be included, the agent searches through `snmpTargetAddrTable` for any rows where `snmpTargetAddrParams` is equal to `snmpNotifyFilterProfileName`.
3. For each `SnmpTagValue` of `snmpTargetAddrTagList` of each `snmpTargetAddrTable` row determined above, `snmpNotifyTable` is scanned for rows with equal `snmpNotifyTag` value to determine the type of notification(s) to be sent (traps or informs).
4. The same `snmpTargetAddrParams` value for the `snmpTargetAddrTable` row in (2) is used to find the corresponding `snmpTargetParamsTable` row where `snmpTargetAddrParams` is equal to `snmpTargetParamsName`. The information in this row is used to determine the SNMP version, security level, and security name to use to send the notification(s) for the target.
5. Depending on the SNMP version, the `snmpTargetParamsSecurityName` determined in (4) corresponds either to an entry in `snmpCommunityTable` (for SNMPv1/v2c) or `usmUserTable` (for SNMPv3/USM).

Comment: Right, that part I understand. but what is the relationship between an RFC 2981 generated MteEventNotification and the SnmpNotifyTable. I could see at least two possible interpretations where the snmpNotifyName maps to 1) mteEventName, or 2) the name of the trap pointed to by the mteEventNotifiction. But neither of these seem to agree with the example provided in RFC 3413.

The example in RFC 3413 indicates that snmpNotifyName might be "group1" (i.e., the same as the tag), but this seems illogical to me. How do I know which notifications are associated with "group1" vs "group2"?

Comment: I have updated the answer with additional information/procedures.

Comment: Note: I'm not particularly familiar with DISMAN-EVENT-MIB; the paragraph about that is what I gathered from a quick scan of it. But the procedures should otherwise be correct for any notification OID an agent is going to send.

Comment: Interesting, so what happens if there an snmpTargetAddrTable row that has three SnmpTagValues in its snmpTargetAddrTagList (Step 3) where one indicates an inform and two indicate trap? Do I send three notifications (one inform and two identical traps); two notifications (combining the two traps as they'd be redundant); one notification (implementer's pick); any of the above (implementer's pick)?

Comment: My interpretation (as I've interpreted/implemented/fixed bugs for two different clients with different agents) is that you would send all three notifications. It may be subject to implementer interpretation as it's a bit ambiguous, but my feeling/experience is that it's far more complicated or subject to not sending what the person who set up the tables wants to implement anything other than sending all three.

Comment: Another way of looking at it/reason to interpret it that way, is that it would not serve much purpose for snmpTargetAddrTagList to take a list of tags instead of a single tag if only a single notification is to be sent.